# How can I close the websocket from server?

Tags: websocket, playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.1.

I am work with web-socket and  I need  to find way to close them from server.

is there way do do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example from docs [Handling WebSockets](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaWebSockets):

> Let’s write another example that totally discards the input data and closes the socket just after sending the Hello! message:

```
public static WebSocket<String> index() {
    return new WebSocket<String>() {

        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
            out.write("Hello!");
            out.close()
        }
   }
}
```

[ScalaWebSockets](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaWebSockets):

```
def index = WebSocket.using[String] { request => 

    // Just consume and ignore the input
    val in = Iteratee.consume[String]()

    // Send a single 'Hello!' message and close
    val out = Enumerator("Hello!") >>> Enumerator.eof

   (in, out)
}
```